# How do I deal with the issue of my divs being distorted greatly when zoomed in?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There are two issues in the code I've written that I'm unsure how to resolve:

How the page looks on Google Chrome

[image: Google Chrome]

That my two columns of `div`s do not scale together as I zoom in and out.

[image]

If I zoom in past a certain amount, the `div`s bust out their containers and distort the webpage completely.

[image]

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtcrn/) the fiddle with the relevant HTML and CSS code for anyone who'd like to look at it.

I would like for the divs to be scaled up or down in position when the user zooms in or out.

EDIT: Up to line #130 are the relevant CSS tags describing the elements that I coded for this page, the rest of the CSS is from Bootstrap and is irrelevant (to this problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do that you have to assign a value to the width or container width of the div. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
body{
        font-size:36px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
.mega_cont{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10%;
    width:710px;
    }
.super_cont_lhs{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    margin-right:5px;
    }

.cont1{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    color:#CCC;
    }
.cont2{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#CCC;
    }
.super_cont_rhs{
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#F60;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="mega_cont">
<div class="super_cont_lhs">
    <div class="cont1">P - S P E C T R A</div>
    <div class="cont2">B E G I N</div>
</div>
<div class="super_cont_rhs">
P-Spectra enables practicing engineers to design seismic retrofit solutions with supplemental dampers using performance based design. 
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I learned a lot by reading your clean code.

Answer (score 2):

What's your desired effect? When they zoom in, it's as if the whole page is scaled? or you want the background etc to remain static and only zoom in the foreground content?

Short of that, you can disable the scale, so that these types of distortions can never happen:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: I pasted that under `<head>`, doesn't seem to behave any differently. Try it out in the fiddle? I want the page to look like it's been scaled when one zooms in or out...

Comment: To be perfectly honest, your issue is that everything is fixed width and height, meaning if you change your window width or zoom in, the containers will overlap especially when using position absolute, which you seem to be doing alot, try re designing your layout using floated elements.

Comment: Have a read of this: http://cameronmoll.com/archives/2009/06/page_zooming_vs_text_scaling/

Comment: Sorry this is probably a daft question, but what exactly are floated elements? The link doesn't describe it.

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't write the code on the page then? adding css like `float: left;` to your elements. Please have a read of http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: I did write the code on the page that you're seeing, I used Bootstrap's sticky footer template, so that might explain some of the CSS at the bottom of the stylesheet in the Fiddle you're seeing. Will do, thank you. To clarify, your solution is to position the elements using floats instead of fixed width and heights?

Comment: Adding `float:left;` to the containers of the `divs` holding the squares you see change nothing either, the behaviour of the `divs` remains the same as I zoom in and out.

Comment: Your whole layout code is wrong, you need to do more research on how to properly code a website. I'd start using boilerplate, it's a html5 template that's just great for base templates.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that it is not the zoom that breaks your design, it's the browser change in dimensions.

Try setting the zoom to 50%, and then changing the browser window to half the size. Your display is again correct, isn't it ?

Now keep the zoom at 100%, and just change the browser dimensions. It breaks anyway, doesn't it ?

When you mix pixels and % in the dimensions, your layout is highly dependent on the size of the browser. To avoid that, you can use only pixels, or only %, but not mixed. (Or mixed controlling very well where you mix them !)

When you zoom in, and don't change your browser size, it's like you make the browser size smaller (according to the new zoom factor)

Answer (score 0):

you have to design the liquid page .
Make the pages responsive and your above problem will simply disappear. 
Also for the responsive design page better to use bootstrap.
Bootstrap will make you easy for responsive design.
Here is the link to download the bootstrap all the instruction to use it...
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Basically, make it two columns instead of 3 positioned blocks. get rid of all of the explicit `width`s, and lose the absolute positioning. Then set `display:inline-block` (or as @ShannonHochkins said you could use `float:left`. I just prefer inline-blocks) and %-based widths.

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/Dtcrn/1/

I removed a lot of extra code (`<head>`, `<script>`, etc) - it's not extra on your site, it just makes the jsFiddle cleaner.

Here's a bare-bones example of how to mae the 2 columns:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="nav_bar">
        [ ... ]
    </div>

    <div id="about_block">
        [ ... ]
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav_bar,
#about_block{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left:-4px;
    width:25%;
}
#about_block{
    width:75%;
}
```